# EXC_BAD_ACCESS at [self.tableView reloadData]

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, exc-bad-access

I'm making a simple app that makes some calculations. Some of these calculations are rather complex, so it may take a while to get the result. I'm using `UITableView` to let user input the values. Then after clicking the "Calculate" button I make a simple `UIView` with an `UIActivityIndicatorView` on it and I put it in the middle of the screen. And then I call the calculating method in the background. Some code:

```
    self.activityIndicatorView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(320/2 - 50, (480 - 64)/2 - 50, 100, 100)];
    self.activityIndicatorView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f;
    self.activityIndicatorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0. green:0. blue:0. alpha:0.7];
    UIActivityIndicatorView *actInd = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    actInd.frame = CGRectMake((100 - actInd.frame.size.width) / 2, (100 - actInd.frame.size.height) / 2, actInd.frame.size.width, actInd.frame.size.height);
    [actInd startAnimating];
    [self.activityIndicatorView addSubview:actInd];
    [self.activityIndicatorView bringSubviewToFront:actInd];
    [self.view addSubview:self.activityIndicatorView];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.activityIndicatorView];
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(calculateAllThatShizzle) withObject:nil];
```

As you see, it is pretty simple. But if the keyboard is still visible it crashes(`EXC_BAD_ACCESS`) when it gets to `[self.tableView reloadData]` in the `-(void)calculateAllThatShizzle` method with that in the log:

```
2012-03-23 11:06:32.418 MyApp[869:5c07] bool _WebTryThreadLock(bool), 0x6adb270: Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. This may be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing now...
1   WebThreadLock
2   -[UITextRangeImpl isEmpty]
3   -[UITextRange(UITextSelectionAdditions) _isCaret]
4   -[UITextSelectionView setCaretBlinks:]
5   -[UIKeyboardImpl setCaretBlinks:]
6   -[UIKeyboardImpl setDelegate:force:]
7   -[UIKeyboardImpl setDelegate:]
8   -[UIPeripheralHost(UIKitInternal) _reloadInputViewsForResponder:]
9   -[UIResponder _finishResignFirstResponder]
10  -[UIResponder resignFirstResponder]
11  -[UITextField resignFirstResponder]
12  -[UITableView reloadData]
13  -[ChildViewController calculateAllThatShizzle]
14  -[NSThread main]
15  __NSThread__main__
16  _pthread_start
17  thread_start
```

So the problem is that it is trying to do something with the keyboard from a background thread. I've tried looping through the cells and call `[cell.rightTextField resignFirstResponder]`, but it doesn't help. I also tried using that

```
-(void)reloadTableViewData {
  [self.tableView reloadData];
}
-(void)calculateAllThatShizzle {
  //some code omitted - code that uses UIKit
  if ([dob timeIntervalSinceDate:calcDate]>0) {
            [errorButton setTitle:@"Calculation Date must be more than Date of Birth" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            errorButton.hidden = NO;
            [self.activityIndicatorView removeFromSuperview];
            self.activityIndicatorView = nil;
            return;
        }
  [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadTableViewData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}
```

but it doesn't help either. I'm using `ELCTextfieldCell`

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you

P.S. I did check some other questions about `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` on reloadData, but it doesn't cover the problem that I have

P.P.S. I can also just run the calculations in the main thread, but then GUI becomes unresponsive and the activity indicator doesn't show up

Comment: did you use custom cell?

Comment: @sch it is in `-(void)calculateAllThatShizzle` method instead of just `[self.tableView reloadData];`

Comment: @HChouhan02 yes, `ELCTextfieldCell`. It provides a label and a textField. It can be found [here](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/elctextfieldcell)

Comment: are there any methods that interact with UI-classes hidden behind `// some code omitted`? For example `[self.activityIndicatorView removeFromSuperView];`?

Comment: yes, but they are not getting called. They stand in the checks with `return;` at the end of the if-clause. Example is the **edit** of the question

Comment: +1 for calculateAllThatShizzle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code

```
for(int i=0;i<[tblViewData count];i++)
{
    if([[(ELCTextfieldCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]] rightTextField] isFirstResponder])
    {
        [[(ELCTextfieldCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]] rightTextField] resignFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

do change according to you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it doesn't work. I used it just before the first line of code in the question.

Comment: oh, figured it out. It is a correct answer, I just had to clean the project. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Suggestion:

- make the tableView the firstResponder *before* you call calculateAllThatShizzle, i.e. force the current first responder to resign and thus dismiss they keyboard
- and then DEFER the call to the calculateAllThatShizzle to after the current run loop has completed, i.e. ensure that the code to dismiss the keyboard gets run at a suitable time

So, something like this:

```
[[self tableView] becomeFirstReponder]; // will dismiss keyboard
[[self performSelector: @selector(startBackgroundStuff) withObject: nil afterDelay: 0.0];
```

Then in your startBackgroundStuff you can put in your:

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(calculateAllThatShizzle) withObject:nil];
```

In the method you definitely want to make sure the reloadData method is called on the main thread. The way you've done looks OK. . You can also do the following:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self reloadTableViewData];
    });
```

(I don't know if one is better than the other, just that what follows definitely works reliably.)

**Supplementary comment**

In calculateAllThatShizzle you are making an UIKit call from the background in some conditions, i.e. `[self.activityIndicatorView removeFromSuperview];` That is likely to cause a crash. UIKit calls need to be on main thread.

In

Comment: thanks for the answer, but `[[self tableView]becomeFirstResponder];` didn't dismiss the keyboard. And thanks for the supplementary comment, I'll test it

Comment: OK. I'd be surprised if it didn't dismiss they keyboard, though, of course, it can only do so after the run loop has completed. And it looks like you have a solution.